# Is there any differences between @RequestMapping("/delete/{id}") and @RequestMapping( value = "/delete/{id}")?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm wondering whether there is any differences between @RequestMapping("/delete/{id}") and @RequestMapping( value = "/delete/{id}") or not.
One is not using "value = " and the other is using "value = ".

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no difference. When an annotation attribute is named `value`, you can omit it (unless you also use other attributes). That is true for all annotations, not just RequestMapping.

See [the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.3) for more details:

> A single-element annotation, is a shorthand designed for use with single-element annotation types (§9.6.1).
>
> SingleElementAnnotation:
>
> ```
> @ TypeName ( ElementValue )
> ```
>
> It is shorthand for the normal annotation:
>
> ```
> @TypeName(value = ElementValue)
> ```
>
> It is legal to use single-element annotations for annotation types with multiple elements, so long as one element is named value and all other elements have default values (§9.6.2).